# RFID tag emulator

Tags: arduino, rf, wireless, rfid

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to emulate 13.56Mhz RFID Mifare tags using an Arduino and basic components.  I have tested some ideas but I couldn't read bytes due to difference in protocols and frequencies.  I even opened a new Mifare 1k tag and soldered its coil to the circuit to avoid errors in induction calculation and I have calculated the frequency but I'm out of luck. I found many similar projects for 125kHz but I have the RC522 RFID reader so I can't test 125kHz yet.

For 125kHz, I found this, as well as this.

This is the code I have used

```
int coil_pin = 9;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Set pin as output
    pinMode(coil_pin, OUTPUT);

   //Start it as low
   digitalWrite(coil_pin, LOW);
}

//Does manchester encoding for signal and sets pins.
//Needs clock and signal to do encoding
void set_pin_manchester(int clock_half, int signal)
{
   //manchester encoding is xoring the clock with the signal
   int man_encoded = clock_half ^ signal;

   //if it's 1, set the pin LOW (this will tune the antenna and the reader 
    sees this as a high signal)
   //if it's 0, set the pin to HIGH  (this will detune the antenna and the 
    reader sees this as a low signal)
 if(man_encoded == 1)
 {
     digitalWrite(coil_pin, LOW);
 }
 else
 {
      digitalWrite(coil_pin, HIGH);
 }
      Serial.println(man_encoded);

 }

 void loop()
 {
 //this is the card data we're spoofing.  It's basically 10 hex F's
 int data_to_spoof[64] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,0 ,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,1,1,0  
 ,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,1,1,0 ,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,1,1,0 ,1,1,1,1,0, 1,1,1,1,0 
 ,1,1,1,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0};
 for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
 {
     set_pin_manchester(0, data_to_spoof[i]);
     delayMicroseconds(5);

     set_pin_manchester(1, data_to_spoof[i]);
     delayMicroseconds(5); 
   }
 }
```

The schematics:

[image]

I also tried this, with differences in the capacitor and inductor values as I'm working with 13.56MHz:

[image]

Comment: "i've tested some idea" is anything but a clear problem statement.

Comment: seriously man: i even open a new Mifare 1k tag and solder its coil to the circuit to avoid error in induction

Comment: it's a lot of trial and errors for the last couple days even me can't remember all what i tested

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can we encourage you to capitalise and punctuate properly for legibility and credibility. Your Arduino compiler wouldn't let you away with it.

Comment: sure i will review it

Comment: the question looks much better now, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone like me will be looking for a solution. I found a project on tiny85.
https://www.nonan.net/nkruse/simplenfc